# Moving from Excel VB to VB.Net Document Customization

Tags: vb.net, vsto

I have been writing Excel Macros using the embedded VB Editor in Excel for a long time.  Now we are trying to move a project over to Visual Studio to take advantage of the features of VB.net and TFS services.  Would one of you VB.NET experts be so kind as to give me an example of what this VB code below would look like as VB.NET?  The project in question is an Excel document customization on VSTO.  I've found plenty of posts out there on Excel plugins, but not many useful that are related to customization projects.  I can't figure out something as simple as taking a String, using it to grab a sheet and then change a few attributes of the sheet.

```
Sub ProcessSheet(sheet As String, box As Boolean)
   With Sheets(sheet)
     If box = True Then
        .Visible = True
     Else
        .Visible = False
     End If
   End With
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance.  If I can get a few pointers I'm sure I'll be able to run with it from there.

Comment: I am not too good at Excel but the last parameter of your sub needs a data type. Not good to name it the same as a type `c As Color`

Comment: You're right @Mary, it worked in Embedded vb, but that is part of the errors I'm getting when I try to write this in VB.NET.   In this case those it's trivial, I'll remove that part of the sub to avoid confusion.

Comment: In case you have not realized it yet, the primary concept to grasp is that you are programming against the  [Excel Object Model API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wss56bz7.aspx)   (using:  VBA, VB.Net, C#, etc.)  and this API is library of [COM interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694363(v=vs.85).aspx).  VBA allows for loose data typing. VB.Net with `Option Strict Off` approximates this loose data typing; .Net enforces strong data typing and this is where many problems begin.  Enable `Option Strict` to enforce strong typing.

Comment: VSTO is project template that sets up framework to work with Excel object model and adds some features. You do not need use it and many people do not. You can add a project reference to the Excel Object Model to any project via the Project Menu->Add Reference->COM Tab->Microsoft Excel xx.y Object Library.  Then add `Imports Excel=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` to your code to facilitate referencing the Excel types.  As in the VBA IDE, use the `Object Browser` (View Menu->Object Browser) to inspect the types.

Comment: As SO is not meant to provide tutorials and this question will likely be closed, I suggest that you research "Excel Automation" and you will find many examples.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with a C# Solution.  If anyone is interested, the VSTO Equivalent of the code I posted is as follows:

```
   private void ProcessSheet(string Sheet, bool visible){
        if (!visible)
        {
            ((Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisWorkbook.Sheets[Sheet])
            .Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetHidden;
        }
        else
        {
            ((Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisWorkbook.Sheets[Sheet])
            .Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible;
        }

    }
```